# How to disable ondblclick in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to disable the `ondblclick` event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.ondblclick = function() { return false; }
```

...or if you didn't want to do it site-wide.

```
document.getElementById('something').ondblclick = function() { return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation(); 
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.ondblclick = function DoubleClick(evt) {
    if (window.getSelection)
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if (document.selection)
        document.selection.empty();
}
</script>
```

This code will disable selecting text via double click