# How do I disable ondblclick in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

So, I've already tried the selected answer on this:

[How to disable ondblclick in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340981/how-to-disable-ondblclick-in-javascript)

but it doesn't work, on my end. As per usual, I'm suspecting it has something to do with IE8 (since a lot of my previous problems were related to IE8 issues).

This is how my button looks like, keyBtnEvent is a function that changes the class of the div:

```js
function keyBtnEvent(key, id, event) {
  //change class of object with id = 'id'
  console.log(event + 'event of keyBtnEvent called');
}
```

```html
<div id="2Key" class="key"
  onmouseup="keyBtnEvent('2','2Key','up')"
  onmousedown="keyBtnEvent('2','2Key','down')">
  <button>2</button>
</div>
```

So, how do i disable ondblclick in IE8, without using jquery?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the `keyBtnEvent()` function. Based on the code you have shown, it should possibly (probably) be `onmouseXYZ="return keyBtnEvent(...)"` (that is, return the value from the function, assuming it returns `false` when you want to cancel the event).

Comment: are you saying that i should add a `ondblclick="return keyBtnEvent('2', '2key', 'dblclick')"`??

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that your existing events didn't include `ondblclick`. Just adding an `ondblclick="return false"` attribute should do it. (Not that I normally recommend inline event attributes, but since you are already using them for the other events.)

Comment: Can you please clearly state what it is you expect here? Even with double click disabled, single clicks will still happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper IE 8 way to do it:

```
var key = document.getElementById('2Key')

// Feature detection for DOM Event Standard and IE 8 and less
if(window.addEventListener){
  // W3C DOM Event Standard
  key.addEventListener("dblclick", function(evt) { 
    evt.preventDefault();    // stop the event
    evt.stopPropagation();  // don't bubble the event
  });
} else if(window.attachEvent){
  // IE 8 or less
  key.attachEvent("ondblclick", function(evt) { 
    evt = evt || window.event;
    evt.returnValue = false;  // stop the event
    evt.cancelBubble = true;  // don't bubble the event
  });
}
```

Also, you should not be using inline HTML event attributes (`onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, etc.). **[Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** Instead, you should be doing all your JavaScript work in a dedicated script and use `.addEventListener()` (or the above `attachEvent()` method for IE 8 or less).

Comment: this does not work for me... i knew that dblclick is still not disabled because the button class doesn't change on a dblclick (when it's supposed to - i.e. mousedown changes the button class, but only does so for the first click)

Comment: i commented before your edit. so uhm... yeah, let me try it out first.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say that *the button class doesn't change on a dblclick* - that's the whole point - to disable the double click event. Here is a working Fiddle with a simulated `keyBtnEvent` function. https://jsfiddle.net/11Ln4ago/9/

Comment: @RobG IE 8 does not support `.addEventListener()`. It wasn't added until IE 9. And, while certainly not a bad idea to test against the object being called, with `.addEventListener()` it doesn't matter because it was implemented across the board, not object by object. See compatibility at bottom of: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: There you go, had the wrong version loaded. ;-) But I also thought that *addEventListener* was supported in IE 8, confirmation bias I guess, should have trusted [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). In any case, this isn't the OP's issue.